# Web Audio Api: audioContext.createConstantSource() isn't implemented in Safari; workaround(s)?

Tags: javascript, safari, webkit, web-audio-api

I am using the web audio api to make a series of demonstrations of simple computer music / electronic music concepts. In one example, I show how to build a `square wave` by successively adding sine waves going up the harmonic series, and displaying an oscilloscope view of the process.

I am including an input range slider to adjust the fundamental frequency at will, which requires the use of a constantSourceNode: the frequencies of all of the oscillators need to be changed simultaneously, otherwise, they get out of phase, ruining the visuals of the demonstration. I've got it working great in chrome, but it seems that

```
audioContext.createConstantSource()
```

is not supported in Safari. Any suggestions for a workaround / alternate implementation?

([Here is a link to a codepen of the demonstration, working in chrome](https://codepen.io/jon-myers/pen/BaoppXe)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari does not yet have an implementation for the `ConstantSourceNode`. If you want to keep your code the way it is you could use [standardized-audio-context](https://github.com/chrisguttandin/standardized-audio-context) which includes an implementation of the `ConstantSourceNode` for browsers which don't support it natively.

But you could also build your own if you prefer that. A looped `AudioBufferSourceNode` with a constant signal and a `GainNode` can be used to achieve the same effect. The `AudioBuffer` used with the `AudioBufferSourceNode` needs to have at least two samples because if it only has one sample Safari will not loop it.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to build my own, as you suggested. I believe I have implemented it correctly; I create an `AudioBufferSourceNode`, fill it with a looping buffer that is 1 sample long, and have my input range slider update the underlying buffer channel data. I then attach this to the detune audioParam of each of my oscillators via `AudioBufferSourceNode.connect(Oscillator.detune)`. Again, it works fine in Chrome, but the detune doesn't seem to be doing anything in Safari. No error message, just doesn't work. (here's the new codepen: https://codepen.io/jon-myers/pen/bGVqbKr)

Comment: Unfortunately there is another bug in Safari which prevents it from looping a single sample buffer. The buffer has to have at least two samples. I will update my answer to mention that as well.

Comment: @jon-myers – how are you updating the underlying channel data? I've tried doing that (for samples, not the `ConstantSourceNode` workaround), and my experience was that browsers will ignore attempts to change the buffer once it's started playing.

Comment: (edit: that said, if taking this approach, you could always feed it through a gain node whose gain you're attenuating, as an alternative to editing in-flight buffer data. Still, I'm curious how you achieved it)

Comment: hmm, I haven't run into that problem. First I assign the buffer channel data to a variable, and then I fill that with whatever the new value is. `bufferData = audioContext.bufferSourceNode.buffer.getChannelData(0); bufferData.fill(newValue)`

Comment: @Luxocrates Now I am running into that problem, but only in firefox. It seems possible to update buffers on-the-fly in other browsers. I added a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61567545/web-audio-api-updating-looping-buffer-data-in-real-time-impossible-in-firebox)  to address this

Comment: Wow, that's wild... I definitely remember trying and failing to do that on Chrome a couple months ago, and finding some official documentation that says explicitly that you can't change a buffer source once playback has started, but I can't find that anywhere now.